# JDBC restful SQL request for TDengine

Tags: tdengine

My springboot project has correctly configured JDBC of TDengine:

```
  datasource:
    dynamic:
      druid:
        max-active: 20
        initial-size: 4
        min-idle: 4
        max-wait: 60000
        time-between-eviction-runs-millis: 60000
        min-evictable-idle-time-millis: 300000
        test-while-idle: false
        test-on-borrow: false
        test-on-return: false
        filters: stat
      primary: td-engine
      strict: false
      datasource:
        td-engine:
          driver-class-name: com.taosdata.jdbc.rs.RestfulDriver
          url: jdbc:TAOS-RS://192.168.1.161:6041/taoskeeper?timezone=UTC-8&charset=UTF-8&locale=en_US.UTF-8
          username: ****
          password: ****
```

When I execute on a existed table: table1:

```
select * from table1
```

```
{\"status\":\"error\",\"code\":535,\"desc\":\"Database not specified or available\"}
```

I got the result of not specified or available error, even I execute "use mydatabase" first.

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC restful api is stateless, which means database has to be selected in sql, the correct sql statement should be :

```
select * from mydatabase.table1
```